# Why is the exit status always 0 at the start of a script?

Tags: exit

I have a script like this, named `judge`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "last exit status is $?"
```

It always outputs "last exit status is 0". Eg:

```
ls -l;   judge # correctly reports 0
ls -z;   judge # incorrectly reports 0
beedogs; judge # incorrectly reports 0
```

Why?

Comment: I'm guessing the answer is "$? is local to the current shell process and the script is a subprocess"

Comment: That is exactly why. There are different `bash` processes executing each line of code and `$?` isn't shared between the processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different bash processes executing each line of code and `$?` isn't shared between the processes. You can work around this by making `judge` a bash function:

```
[root@xxx httpd]# type judge
judge is a function
judge ()
{
    echo "last exit status is $?"
}
[root@xxx httpd]# ls -l / >/dev/null 2>&1; judge
last exit status is 0
[root@xxx httpd]# ls -l /doesntExist >/dev/null 2>&1; judge
last exit status is 2
[root@xxx httpd]#
```

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, the $? variable holds the value from the last process that returned a value to the shell.

If `judge` needs to do something based on a previous command state, you could have it accept a parameter, and pass in the state.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "last exit status is $1"
# Or even 
return $1
```

So:

```
[cmd args...]; judge $?
```

Comment: Oops, transcription error. I meant "$1".